# Object Property Scope

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to declare a private variable inside class which I want to access in all of my class without passing it to another function using parameter. I have following scenario

```
class One extends CI_Controller {
    private $name;
    public function index () {
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $this->validate();
    }

    public function validate() {
        echo $name;
    }
}
```

But my above $name variable gives me an error saying `variable $name is undefined`.

Is above possible in PHP if yes then how?

Comment: in function should use $this->name

Comment: http://php.net/language.oop5.properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just using `$name` is a local variable in the scope of the function only.

If you use `$this->name`, you can access the private property of your controller.

See [Properties<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/language.oop5.properties).

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a variable in a class, you will have to use `$this->` to call it.

Therefore, the way you call it inside a method is by using `$this->name` instead of `$name`